# Loading .xlsb file through power query from share point

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, xlsx, xlsb

I have a bunch of files that are usually updated with power query from other excel files in .xlsx format. But recently they'd become too big (about 250Mb), so I decided to switch them to .xlsb. However, all querys have become extreamly slow: refreshment time have increased form ~5 min to 30+ min. The Internet connection remains the same, so it's unlikely that the slow-down is due to Internet speed.

I didn't manage to find any relevant info in google, maybe here anybudy knows if it is possible to make .xlsb files load more quickly.

Comment: Why not just continue to use the `xlsx` type files, since they seem to be working better.  I don't know about today, but in the past others have reported that PQ + XLSB is much slower than PQ + XLSX and at one time wouldn't even work.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, the problem with xlsx is that the are too big and are very slow when it comes to openning them. To avoid this i tried to switch to xlsb, that on the one hand accelerated the opening speed, but on the other hand slowed PQ

Comment: Maybe try using `Table.Buffer` (if the disadvantages don't apply to your query). If that doesn't work, consider storing your data in something other than an Excel file.  Different data sources get processed differently by PQ so far as speed is concerned.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld , thanks, haven't used this method before, will look int it.